# make variable available to first tab when var is defined in second tab

Tags: swift, tabs

When I define a variable in the first tab I can then make it available in the usual way to the other tabs. But what if I define a variable in the third tab and I want it to be available in the first tab? Here is the usual set up for the variable in the first tab:

```
class AddCardViewController: UIViewController {

    var cards = [Card]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cards = [1,2,3,4]

    let barViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
    let svc1 = barViewController![1] as! LearningViewController
    svc1.cards = self.cards
    }
```

in the second viewController I can then easily use the cards array

```
class LearningViewController: UIViewController {

    var cards = [Card]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(cards)  ////works all fine
```

Now I want to define a variable in the second tab and make it available to the first tab. So, the other way round. I tried to use the same setup, but when I start the app it crashes because the variable is nil in the first tab - makes sense. Is there any way to do this or do I just have to define all variables in the first viewController?

Comment: If you need to work with the same data in multiple tabs, it would be a good idea to handle that in a separate class that can be accessed by both ViewControllers

Comment: good idea, I am sure that would work, however, as a matter of interest, I'd still like to know, whether there is a solution to the  above

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ    just working on your suggestion, but there is the same issue, what if I have to define the object of the class in the second ViewController and then use the object in the first ViewController. Does my question make sense? I am a beginner

Comment: Is the variable essential to both classes or only relevant when the class that originally owns it is instantiated?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand, but here's an example: secondVC sets the value of a static variable, and the firstVC checks that variable and sets up accordingly in viewWillAppear

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson    I need the variable in both classes, so, when I change it in the first one I should change in the second one, vici versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to force the second tab to load before calling the variable in question. The most brute force way to do this is to create a func in AddCardViewController that loads all the tabs in the tabBarController e.g.

```
func loadAllTabs() {
    if let viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            viewController.view
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
    loadAllTabs()
}
```